# Grails Many to One Relationship Failed to Save Foreign Keys

Tags: grails

I'm building a REST API where I have an Image domain which belongs to two other classes.

```
class Image {

static belongsTo=[location:Location,port:Port]
//image url
String url    
}
```

and Here is the location domain:

```
class Location {

    static hasMany = [images:Image]
}
```

The same goes for port domain. The problem is that when I'm saving the port domain object with images array of objects port get saved and images get saved but the foreign keys in images table are null so like the image is not related to any port or location. The request data is being sent as JSON body and bound to port instance.

```
mysql> select * from image;
+----+---------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | version | location_id | port_id | url                                                                                   |
+----+---------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 |       0 |        NULL |    NULL | https://url/d6d89de902259491de430563d2f60aac.png |
```

Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: how do you assign images to port and save?

Comment: I didn't assign it I suppose that this should be auto bound? Isn't this a bidirectional relationship?

Comment: no it shouldn't. you have to either fulfill the relations explicitly or use helper methods `addTo*()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012112/auto-binding-a-grails-one-to-many-relationship this link solved my problem